# Overruling global node style in matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, tikz-styles, tikz-matrix

I want to build a matrix of several nodes of different types. In my example there is a matrix containing two "modules" and one "label".
For convenience I wanted to use `matrix of nodes` with `nodes={module}` since there are modules than labels.
Now, if I want to set the style of the label, I would usually use `|[label]|` as in:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
    module/.style={draw, rectangle, fill=white, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=0.8cm},
    label/.style={ }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[fill=black!20, matrix of nodes, nodes={module}]
    {
        |[label]| Label \\ % this  doesn't produce the desired output
        Module 1        \\
        Module 2        \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Example]

Sure I could just specify every node explicitly, but this seems quite cumbersome. Is there a better solution?

Comment: I am afraid there is no easy way but define an opposite style: `label/.style={draw=none,fill=none}`

Comment: Thanks, such an easy solution. I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `label` is predefined style in TikZ, for my answer I'll use `mymodule` and `mylabel` in place of `module` and `label`.

What is happening here is that when you put `nodes={mymodule}` and then `|[mylabel]|`, the style of the cell became equivalent to `|[mymodule,mylabel]|`. So if `mylabel/.style={}` finaly the style of your cell is just like for all other cells `|[mymodule]|`.

As @user43963 says in his comment, you have to overwrite the properties that you don't want anymore. Like this:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
    mymodule/.style={draw, rectangle, fill=white, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=0.8cm},
    mylabel/.style={draw=none,fill=none}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[fill=black!20, matrix of nodes, nodes={mymodule}]
    {
        |[mylabel]| Label \\ % this  produce the different output
        Module 1        \\
        Module 2        \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If `label` nodes are only labels to be added to some `module` nodes, there's no need for a new style, just including a `label` option to corresponding node can work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
    module/.style={draw, rectangle, fill=white, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=0.8cm},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[fill=black!20, matrix of nodes, nodes={module}, row sep=-\pgflinewidth]
    {
        |[label=Label]|Module 1        \\
        Module 2     \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: `row sep=-\pgflinewidth` has been added to avoid double thickness lines between rows.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I forgot about the `label` option.